# Getting translations from a table by always including all languages even if there is no translation for it

Tags: mysql

I have 3 MySQL tables:

- translations:
  -- id
  -- name
- translation_details:
  -- id
  -- translation_id
  -- translation
- languages:
  -- language_code

In translations table there are unique names for translations e.g: welcome.title, login, signup etc

For this unique strings, there are localised translations for them in the translation_details table, but some languages may be missing.

In the languages table there are languages that I want to get translations.

I want to make sure every 'translation' will be outputted with its translation data even if there is no any match for it in the translation_details.

For instance,

```
Languages: en, de, it
Translations: test1
Translation details: test1 in English (en), test1 in German (de)
```

So, Italian translation is missing.

How can I write a query that also gets missing translations with null values.

I tried to use right join, but it didn't work.

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    translations
    JOIN translation_details AS td ON td.translation_id = translations.id
    RIGHT JOIN translation_languages AS lang ON lang.language_code = td.language_code
```

This code doesn't output missing translations with null values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create all combinations of `translations` and `translation_languages` in a subquery. Then, do a `LEFT JOIN` to `translation_details` on translation id and language.

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM translations AS t
  CROSS JOIN translation_languages AS tl
) AS dt 
LEFT JOIN translation_details AS td ON td.translation_id = dt.id 
                                       AND td.language_code = dt.language_code
```