# How to show data displayed even not matchiing WHERE condition?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display some data from database using multiple parameters.

```
t_item
ID_ITEM     ITEM     PRICE
      A     Book      1000
      B     Pencil    2000
      C     Pen       3000

t_store_master
ID_STORE       STORE     
    ST01     STORE_1
    ST02     STORE_2
    ST03     STORE_3       

t_store_detail
ID_STORE_DETAIL     ID_STORE    ID_ITEM     LAST_STOCK
              1         ST01          A              5
              2         ST01          B              7
              3         ST02          A              9
              4         ST02          C              4
              5         ST03          C              8
```

I'd like to display the data even when I give non existing value as parameter. If I use not existing value as parameter, there is no data retrieved. Some example of the output:

```
  STORE     ITEM     LAST_STOCK     TOTAL
STORE_1     Book              5      5000     //Parameter: (ID_STORE = 'ST01' and ID_ITEM = 'A')
STORE_1      Pen              0         0     //Parameter: (ID_STORE = 'ST01' and ID_ITEM = 'C')
```

My current query:

```
SELECT 
   t_store_master.STORE, 
   t_item.ITEM,
   t_store_detail.LAST_STOCK,
   (t_store_detail.LAST_STOCK * t_item.PRICE) AS 'TOTAL'  
FROM t_store_master 
   INNER JOIN t_store_detail ON t_store_master.ID_STORE = t_store_detail.ID_STORE 
   INNER JOIN t_item ON t_store_detail.ID_ITEM= t_item.ID_ITEM
WHERE t_store_detail.ID_STORE = '?' AND t_store_detail.ID_ITEM = '?'
```

Note:  -  Is it also possible to display data with these parameter?

```
STORE_6     Book              0         0     //Parameter: (ID_STORE = 'ST06' and ID_ITEM = 'A')
STORE_7        -              0         0     //Parameter: (ID_STORE = 'ST07' and ID_ITEM = 'E')
```

Comment: Cross Join between item and store master tables to get all possible combinations; filter on this result-set; do left join with store_detail table to get matching details (if any). Check this duplicate for a similar idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56849004/2469308

Comment: Will you have multiple combinations of parameters in a single query ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya yes. The Parameter only ID_STORE and ID_ITEM

Comment: Do you still get a row, if the `ID_STORE` value is invalid (no such store exists) ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Yes, if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), based on your Input Parameter values. If you have multiple combinations of input params, you can utilize `UNION` to include them all in a single subquery. Now, you can do a `LEFT JOIN` to all the table(s) to check if any matching row exists or not.

```
SELECT 
   prm.ID_STORE, 
   sm.STORE, 
   prm.ID_ITEM, 
   i.ITEM, 
   sd.LAST_STOCK,
   (sd.LAST_STOCK * i.PRICE) AS TOTAL
FROM 
  -- Change the values in this query depending on parameter accordingly
  (SELECT 'ST07' AS ID_STORE, 'E' AS ID_ITEM
    -- If you have multiple parameter combinations, you can extend this using UNION
   UNION 
   SELECT 'ST06', 'A') AS prm 
LEFT JOIN t_store_master AS sm 
       ON sm.ID_STORE = prm.ID_STORE 
LEFT JOIN t_item AS i 
       ON i.ID_ITEM = prm.ID_ITEM
LEFT JOIN t_store_detail AS sd 
       ON sd.ID_STORE = prm.ID_STORE 
          AND sd.ID_ITEM = prm.ID_ITEM
```

**Result**

```
| ID_STORE | ID_ITEM | STORE | ITEM | LAST_STOCK | TOTAL |
| -------- | ------- | ----- | ---- | ---------- | ----- |
| ST06     | A       |       | Book |            |       |
| ST07     | E       |       |      |            |       |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sTYHDSBG6cLdbsSedFzLi7/0)